# Import Error in flask importing MYSQL in python in vs code?

Tags: python, flask, mysql-python, flask-mysql

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,redirect, 
session,url_for,request
from flask_mysqldb  import MYSQl
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key="12345678"

app.config["MYSQL_HOST"] = "localhost"
app.config["MYSQL_USER"]="root"
app.config["MYSQL_PASSWORD"]="123457"
app.config["MYSQL_DB"] = "management"
db = MYSQL(app)
```

[This is the library code in vs code that do not show error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpHSd.png)

[image: In this snap showing import error while library already installed]

[image: This is the snap of flask mysqldb installed]

I installed mysql. but when i run in python it giving error how do i remove import error for
flask_mysqldb.In  second snap showing import error while library already installed.In third snap, This is the snap of flask mysqldb is installed

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Why do you think `from flask import MYSQL` should work?

Comment: because i am working on this library. i use this for accessing MySQL data

Answer (score 1):

For import MySQL in flask. The Syntax are `from flask_mysqldb  import MySQL`. 'y' always in lowercase in " MySQL"

Answer (score 0):

**Did you install flask-mysql? **

If you haven't, Install it by running the following command in command prompt.

`pip install flask-mysql`

If you've already installed flask-mysql, as I can see from the screenshots of the error your **import statement is incorrect**,

Import it as:

`from flask_mysql  import MySQL`

Comment: This line giving same error on flaskext .mysql

Comment: Probably MySQL, not MYSQL.

Comment: but still giving error by MySQL

Comment: I replace MYSQL with MySQL. In my previous library it will solved.